# Does msync() provide acquire/release semantic?

Tags: linux, multithreading

Two threads A and B share the same mapped region with the following layout

```
struct header_layout
{
    // cache line #1
    struct alignas( cache_line_size )
    {
        int64_t free_ptr_;
        size_t  crc_;
        int64_t free_ptr_copy_;
    }garbage_;

    // cache line #2
    struct alignas( cache_line_size )
    {
        int64_t offset_;
        int64_t value_;
        size_t  crc_;
    }transaction_;
};
```

and write `garbage_` and `transaction_` fields independently under different locks. The problem is that `msync()` respects memory granularity, i.e. flushing of `transaction_` field also causes flushing of `garbage_`.

Taking a mutex thread B (gonna write `transaction_`) gets the guarantee that CPU cache is synchronized, i.e. the cached line #1 is either ACTUAL or INVALIDATED. The second case is trivial. But what would happen if the cache line was ACTUAL at the moment of taking mutex? Thread B writes to `transaction_` (cache line #2) and does not touch `garbage_`( cache line #1), but thread A may write `garbage_` in concurrent, so thread B won't see the changes and can possibly overwrite changes done by thread A, of course if `msync()` does not provide acquire/release semantics. And that is the question.

Comment: Are these threads in the same process or different processes?

Comment: Sure, they are in the same process and they share the same range of virtual addresses returned by 'mmap()'. This is not about synchronization between physical memory and underlying file, this is about CPU cache coherence